# Eclipse not recognizing apex component -- Most color are dark

Tags: eclipse, colors, apex

I have been trying for the past hours to fix my font colour on eclipse but nothing seems to work. I don't want to work on White theme because I get a headache so I always turn my theme to a darker colour but eclipse does not seem to recognize any component (variable, object, etc) thus almost everything is black on black. I even downloaded the Eclipse color theme plugin and it still doesn't work. 
please help me.
[Eclipse image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJk6D.png)